How do I make cracks in this picture?

Do you think I can add simple cracks to the ground? It's kinda boring or not very detailed, besides the texture. I will be glad if I can add cracks which don't take much time to add. I would like realistic cracks: Not too large, rather small and from this perspective visible

So much for trying to correct your grammar! Rolled back by OP lmao. No problem, keep your bad grammar.

If you want cracks in the ground, something like this may suit your case:

Here's the Picture of the node tree:

You may play with the values a bit, if you want to alter the result. This Setup enables you to change the size, distortion, detail, amount, intensity etc. of the cracks.
Hope it helps

Oops, sorry, I had closed this question down after a few 'Opinion-Based' objections from the community. But if we narrow it down to 'How do I make cracks'  as per your answer, that seems fair enough, so re-opened.

@RobinBetts can I also change to, "How can I add more details to the ground"?

Hi 2sa2..I'm trying to be as reasonable as I can be, within the constraints of the SE format :) . I still think, if you want a nice open discussion of what details you might add to the foreground floor-area, you're better off in a more discursive forum, like Blender Artists. (For instance, I may have a suggestion that  the picture could have more indication of locale.. even a cast shadow could hint at that... but no way could I post it as a rank-able answer on a Stack Exchange page. )

Ok, I understand this, sorry for the trouble on this forum
